# WebView doesn't show anything when using findViewById

Tags: android, android-webview

My WebView doesn't show anything. It is just empty.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <WebView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

  <!--   <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableRow"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonAccept"
            android:layout_width="0sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/button_accept" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonDeny"
            android:layout_width="0sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/button_deny" />
    </LinearLayout> -->

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the Activity:

```
public class TermsOfUseDialogActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.terms_menu_dialog);

        WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
//      WebView webview = new WebView(this);
//      setContentView(webview);

        String htmlCode = "<html><body>WebView Test<br /><br />New Line Test</body></html>";
        // webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, htmlCode, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);

//      webview.clearView();
        webview.loadData(htmlCode, "text/html", "UTF-8");
//      webview.reload();

        // webview.loadUrl("http://www.google.at");
    }
}
```

As you can see I commented some code out. None if these tries worked except this part...

```
WebView webview = new WebView(this);
setContentView(webview);
```

In this case, I see the content but I can't use this, because I need to use buttons shown in the XML above, too. Any ideas why this doesn't show any content?

(Internet permissions are set in AndroidManifest)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. The layout was incorrect. With the following layout, I've got a full screen web view with 2 buttons below:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

  <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/buttonRow"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonAccept"
            android:layout_width="0sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/button_accept" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonDeny"
            android:layout_width="0sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button_deny"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
  </LinearLayout>

    <WebView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_above="@+id/buttonRow"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```